# Remove 3/8" of wood to allow for tile and necessary grout?

Tags: technique, router

I am building a wood desk clock using 6/4 walnut and a clock insert. I want to install a 4" X 4" X 1/4" decorative ceramic tile below the clock. I think I would need to remove 3/8" of wood to allow for the installation of the tile and grout.

What tools and methods would you recommend I employ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Are you looking for recommendations that will require you to buy a specific tool or tools or that will utilise tooling you already have? If the latter you need to tell us what you already have ;-)

Comment: FYI there are three main ways this would be done, most common of which these days would be to use a power router (with some help provided by a sub-base or simple jig). A primarily hand-tool approach would usually require a hand router to finish off neatly and accurately (which again might need an attached sub-base). Third way would typically rely on a bandsaw or tablesaw, but could in theory be done sawing by hand, if you have the requisite saw and experience.

Comment: Grout might not be the best adhesive for installing a tile in a piece of wood. Consider silicone caulk, construction adhesive, or epoxy instead.

Answer (score 1):

A router (powered or hand) is normally the tool used to make an inset in a piece of wood.

I suppose you could use a Forstner bit in a drill press with a depth stop to hog out most of the material, but then you'd need to clean up the bottom because the Forstner bit will leave a mark from the spur at the center. If you wanted, you could buy a cheap bit and file off the spur for this project.

Comment: I'm waiting for the OP to clarify whether they want to use existing tools; let's see how long that wait is #_# Regardless, it occurred to me that *all* methods require a chisel (and a sharp one at that, because by necessity some of the cuts are across the grain).